# socket.io - Serializing Sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Is there anything out of the box that allows serializing and deserializing sockets?  I've looked all over and can't really seem to find anything on this subject.  If convenient (de)serialization doesn't exist, is there a way to build sockets dynamically using their properties so I can just do it manually?

Thanks!

Comment: What purpose would this serve?  When the connection is gone, it's not as if it can be brought back.

Comment: True, but if a cluster goes down and is brought back up, it would be nice to be able to re-establish the connections with its users immediately in a way that is decoupled from session handling.

Comment: If your cluster goes down and is brought back up, you have lost the TCP connections and any new connections are new underlying sockets anyway.  Session data is the appropriate method to deal with this.

Comment: Can you fax a fax machine? Can you SMS an iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

All TCP connections are dynamic by nature - means you can't expect to persist a connection and recover the same at a later point. A connection handle if lost - can be obtained again only by way of re-connecting in which case it is anyways a new handle and the old handle is lost.
This is true about all sockets be it any programming language